# In a part of a range macro overwrites any values to be copied to 0s

Tags: excel, vba

This is a code that should copy from one open workbook (WorkbookA) to the other open one (WorkbookB):

```
Option Explicit

Dim shRange1 As String
Dim shRange2 As String
Dim shRange3 As String
Dim wrk As Workbook
Dim inx As Integer


Public Sub cPasteToWorkbookB()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

For inx = 2 To 6

    chooseInx

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(inx).Range(shRange1).Copy
    
    findOpenWorkbookB
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(inx).Range(shRange1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(inx).Range(shRange2).Copy
    
    findOpenWorkbookB
    
    pasteShRange3


Next inx
    
Set wrk = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

It has the following function for the cases, which are ranges in different worksheets:

```
Function chooseInx()

Select Case inx

    Case 2:
    shRange1 = "C6:S17"
    shRange2 = "K24:L27"
    shRange3 = "C24"
    
    Case 3:
    shRange1 = "C6:W14"
    shRange2 = "K21:L23"
    shRange3 = "C21"
    
    Case 4:
    shRange1 = "C6:S14"
    shRange2 = "K21:L23"
    shRange3 = "C21"
    
    Case 5:
    shRange1 = "C6:S14"
    shRange2 = "K21:L23"
    shRange3 = "C21"
    
    Case 6:
    shRange1 = "C6:U14"
    shRange2 = "K21:L23"
    shRange3 = "C21"

End Select

End Function
```

The code does it's job, but for this part:

```
Case 5:
shRange1 = "C6:S14"
```

the macro seem to change any values to 0 only in range "P6:P14" (it's not a typo) and then pastes the 0s to WorkbookB. This does not happen when I go through the macro with F8 - then I have the values as they were initially in both workbooks. And for Case 4 it works flawlessly, despite the ranges are exactly the same.

Here is the function for browsing all the open workbooks in search for WorkbookB:

```
Function findOpenWorkbookB()
For Each wrk In Workbooks
    If InStr(wrk.Name, "WorkbookB") > 0 Then
    wrk.Worksheets(inx).Activate
    Exit For
End If
Next
End Function
```

Why such result? Why it overwrites the a part that was supposed to be copied only? I struggle to understand what is happening in the process, so I might not be as communicative with this post as I want to be. Any remarks are welcomed, I will adjust the question accordingly.

I tried to slow the macro a bit on different steps (copying, pasting and in the findOpenWorkbookB function), but to no avail.

For your reference below is the shRange1, from Case 5 with affected column P, with sensitive data hidden:[image]

In greyed cells to the right are formulas, the ones from colums Q and R simply sum some cells on the same row from the left, the right extreme one is visible on the screen. None of the formulas refer to column P, the problematic one.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have formulas that evaluate to `0` or `""` in range `P6:P14`. Either delete the formulas or copy the formatting by changing `Paste:=xlPasteValues` to `Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`.

Comment: no, no formulas, values only. changing to `Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` did not solve the issue.

Comment: @Drzemlik, Can you post an example? When running in debug mode, certain things work differently, like pivot tables. Are there any special elements or formulas in your workbooks that may affect those cells?

Comment: true, pivots are in the workbook, but not in the worksheets checked by macro. Formulas are in last three columns of each shRange1, as visible in the example I added to the question.

Comment: No formula on the affected worksheet refers to the troublesome column P, only in Case 2 one of the summing formulas takes values from analogical column P in the Case 2 worksheet. This is because the Case 2 shRange1 is wider than in Case 5 and values fall in different cells. Please note that the affected range is in Case 5, not in Case 4 - I yesterday corrected my initial mistake while building the question.

Comment: the mentioned pivots in the workbook, do not refer to the ranges/worksheets in question; they take data from ranges on separate worksheets.